# JAVA - Sounds not playing after jar exported

Tags: java, audio

I have the problem that after i export my java project no sound is playing.

I searched in the internet and i found that:
`Main.class.getResourceAsStream("fileloc");`solves that problem

But my class uses this.. 
Where is the problem?

```
public class Sounds {

private static Clip eat;
public static Clip collect;
private static Clip lsd;
private static AudioInputStream inputStream;
private static FloatControl gainControl;

public static void getSounds(){
    try{
        eat = getClip("/sound/collect/eat.wav");
        collect = getClip("/sound/collect/collect.wav");
        lsd = getClip("/sound/LSD.wav");
    } catch(LineUnavailableException | UnsupportedAudioFileException| IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static Clip getClip(String loc) throws LineUnavailableException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException{
    Clip c = AudioSystem.getClip();
    inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Spielfeld.class.getResourceAsStream(loc));
    c.open(inputStream);
    gainControl = (FloatControl) c.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
    gainControl.setValue(+6.0f);
    c.setMicrosecondPosition(0);
    return c;
}

public static void playSound(final String url) {
        switch(url){
            case "collect/collect.wav": collect.start(); collect.setMicrosecondPosition(0); break;
            case "collect/eat.wav": eat.start(); eat.setMicrosecondPosition(0); break;
            case "LSD.wav": lsd.start(); lsd.setMicrosecondPosition(0); break;
        }
}
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: What program are you using to compile the jar? Are you making sure to include the sounds with the jar?

Comment: Also what program has the sound effects for Eat, Collect and LSD?

Comment: I use Eclipse and checked the jar via WinRar --> the files are included

Comment: And they are in a folder called sound?

Comment: Also does this help any? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044136/no-sound-after-export-to-jar?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[No sound after export to jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044136/no-sound-after-export-to-jar?rq=1)

Thank you trinityalps ;) (https://stackoverflow.com/users/5012832/trinityalps)

Comment: Pretty annoying bug, I got ot too